How can I remove the "Environment" table from a Pytest-Html report
The following code I found on this website here does not have any effect.
It is suggested to set the metadata=None BUT this has no effect. Here is the code:
def pytest_configure(config):
    config._metadata = None

How can I remove the Environment table from the Pytest-Html report?


To delete the environment table:
You need pytest-metadata plugin.
from pytest_metadata.plugin import metadata_key


def pytest_configure(config):
    config.stash[metadata_key]["foo"] = "bar"

To hide entire environment section:
You can use css, here is how:
Create pytest.ini file and add:
[pytest]

addopts = --css=style.css

Now create style.css and add:
#environment-header,
#environment {
  display: none;
}


Thanks. I used your your script above to remove all entries in the box and the box disappeared. However the title of the box "Environment" remained. Here's my code:
 for i in list(config.stash[metadata_key]):
    config.stash[metadata_key].pop(i)


I have edited the code according to your request. Thanks

You're not completely hiding the environment section because the "Environment" header is still visible. It's simply an  element without an associated ID.
